# Running a script on Slurm Preemption Suspend Event

Tags: linux, signals, slurm, system-administration

I am planning to use different queues with different priorities, and a job on a higher priority queue should suspend a job in the lower priority queue. This mechanism works fine except I would like to catch the event of suspension and run some scripts to release software licenses.

I haven't been able to find any mechanism built-in to do this. I looked into catching system signals sent to the processes. It says in the manual that SIGSTOP and SIGCONT is used for suspending and resuming the processes. However it is not possible to catch these signals.

I made a dummy python script to observe how it works and it looks like slurm sends SIGSTP right before SIGSTOP if you use srun in the batch script otherwise I can't catch any signals.

here is the python and the sbatch scripts I use respectively:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import signal
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def signal_handler_suspend(*args):
        print("Suspended")

    def signal_handler_resume(*args):
        print("Continued")

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, signal_handler_suspend)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGCONT, signal_handler_resume)
    print(os.getpid())
    i=0
    while i<100:
        time.sleep(1)
        i+=1
        print(i)
```

Bash script to submit with sbatch

```sh
#!/bin/bash

./signal_trial
```

So the questions are:

- Is there a better way to do this without trying to catch system signals?
- Why does it send the SIGTSTP(catchable) before SIGSTOP(uncatchable) when I use srun vs without srun it would not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered slurm uses freezer to suspend the processes when you use `ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup` .

It is virtually impossible to catch any signal by design. 
So using `ProctrackType=proctrack/linuxproc` did the trick. Now I can catch the SIGTSTP before SIGSTOP is sent.

This is not the perfect solution of course if you have to use cgroups for process tracking.